# No Resource found error during compilation| Android

Tags: android, android-support-library

This question is being posted after quite some extensive research and failing at finding the solution. When i try to compile my project i get this error:

```
Error:(94, 54) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'android:actionModeCloseDrawable' with value '@drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha').
```

Below is my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

ext {
    supportLibVersion = '25.3.1'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.editor.photoeditor"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile "com.android.support:support-annotations:${supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:${supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${supportLibVersion}"
    compile('com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.1.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile 'com.github.javiersantos:MaterialStyledDialogs:1.4.1'
    compile 'com.github.darsh2:MultipleImageSelect:v0.0.4'
    compile 'com.github.lopei:collageview:0.1.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile 'com.orhanobut:logger:1.11'
    compile 'com.adobe.creativesdk.foundation:auth:0.3.94'
    compile 'com.adobe.creativesdk:image:4.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.QuadFlask:colorpicker:0.0.8'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
    compile 'com.readystatesoftware.systembartint:systembartint:1.0.3'
    compile 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.cocosw:bottomsheet:1.+@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
}
```

What i have tried up till now:

1) Clean Project and Rebuild Project

2) Deleted build folder and rebuilt project

3) upgraded, downgraded to all possible versions between 23.0.0 and final version of support library given in my build.gradle.

4) Gone through almost every article and most of them propose to change the name of variable `@drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha` **to** `R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_materia` but since it is in  `<style name="MD_Dark" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert">` style and problem only shows during compilation, hence, i can not change the name of this item as well.

Comment: why this long long name ? try to short it.

Comment: to make it self explanatory. good enough?

Answer (score 0):

Following bug was resolved by updating support library version to 25.3.1. After updating the support library version rebuild the whole project and don't just sync the gradle afterwards. Only syncing build.gradle my cause the problem to come up again, so rebuild the whole project every time you have sync the gradle.